# Is there a pattern in Cassandra for this task?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I've got 2 tables and basically everything's the same except that in the 1st table we've got *PLAYER_ID* as the last column and in the 2nd table we've got *NUM_OF_PLAYERS* instead.

So here's what I've got:

```
BIRTHDAYS_TABLE:
int year, PLAYER_ID
1988, 12312321 which stands for 'Messi'
1988, 5541 which stands for 'Some other footballer'
1989, 12312322 which stands for 'CR7' etc
```

And then once in a while (once a year for this example) I want to 'cache' these results:

```
NUM_OF_PLAYERS_TABLE:
int year, int NUM_OF_PLAYERS
1988, 2
```

And the only query I support is "give me number of players who were born in X". Is there any solution in Cassandra so I don't have to write a bicycle and create some sort of scheduler (which runs once in a year for this example) and delete rows from the very 1st table and add this count() to the 2nd one?

Obviously my tables aren't that simple, but I believe that the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `count` aggregation, like this:

```
select year, count(*) from first_table where year=1981;
```

then grab value returned as `count`, and insert into your 2nd table.

Actual implementation will depend on programming language that you're using.

Comment: The idea is that there're huge number of players (think about millions) and I'd like to save some space (that's why I want to delete these rows once in a while). I do run your query when doing manual (using scheduler) deleting but I was searching for some neat solution without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Ok, in this case you may need to rethink the data model because with millions of players you may get very wide partitions that may affect Cassandra's performance